# How to get the (i,j)th pair which has distance more than some specified number in R

Tags: r

Let us consider a distance matrix

A<-

```
     [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
 [1,]  0        5165      4100
 [2,] 5165       0        6572
 [3,] 4100      6572       0
```

How to get the which (i,j)^th pair has distance more than 6000 using R?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `which(A>600, arr.ind = T)` is probably what you're after.

Comment: Was about to post an answer, but now it's closed. Nevertheless, if you want not to list duplicate entries (i, j) and (j, i) together, use `zz[zz[, 1] >= zz[, 2], ]`, where `zz <- which(A>600, arr.ind = T)`. You are welcome!

Comment: @tonytonov too bad you didn't. There was a completely shameless copy pasting going here.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Henrik was too fast with the dupehammer while I was trying to compose a sentence about the duplication for symmetrical matrices :) Anyway, thanks for the note.

Comment: @tonytonov The desired output wasn't entirely clear, so I was initially hesitating to close. But after OP had commented on your `arr.ind` suggestion ("It is working. Thanks a lot") I considered it was safe to close as an 'normal' `arr.ind = TRUE` dupe.

Comment: @Henrik I completely agree, and since my addendum is short enough to fit as a comment above, I consider it a win-win.

Answer (score 1):

Use `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE`.

```
> A <- matrix(c(0, 5165, 4100, 5165, 0, 6572, 4100, 6572, 0), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0 5165 4100
[2,] 5165    0 6572
[3,] 4100 6572    0

> which(A>6000, arr.ind=TRUE)

     row col
[1,]   3   2
[2,]   2   3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The same answer is also given by @tonytonov in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` function like this:

```
which(A>6000, arr.ind = T)
```

It returns matrix with two column `row` and `col`. Each row of the matrix -- (i, j) which a[i, j]>6000

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The same answer is also given by @tonytonov in the comments to the question..